# Tried to update field with a model instance, <SimpleLazyObject:<<>>. Use a value compatible with CharField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to over ride the save method in my model to store the currently loged in user. I am using the **django-current** user to get the authenticated user. I wrote this code

```
from django_currentuser.middleware import (
    get_current_user, get_current_authenticated_user)

from django_currentuser.db.models import CurrentUserField

 uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

     user = get_current_authenticated_user()

     self.uploaded_by = user

     super(Citation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I am getting this error

```
Tried to update field professional.Citation.uploaded_by with a model instance, <SimpleLazyObject: <CustomUser: staff@gmail.com>>. Use a value compatible with CharField.
```

What should I do? I want to store the currently logged in user in the model save method and also keep this field non editable.

I am getting this error only when the field is being updated. It is working fine wile saving for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting this error because you are trying to save user object in an char field. Your uploaded_by filed is an  CharField. You can save only string value in this fields.

try this and hope this will solved your problems:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User #import user model
 # add user ForeignKey fields in your model
 user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
 uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    
         user = self.user.username

         if not self.uploaded_by:
             self.uploaded_by = user
    
         super(Citation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it says now 

"'Citation' object has no attribute 'request'"

Comment: @Ritankar Bhattacharjee try now. Updated my question

Comment: Now it says "'Citation' object has no attribute 'user'"

Comment: @Ritankar Bhattacharjee  sorry I forget to add  user fields. please check now

Comment: still the same error "'Citation' object has no attribute 'user'"

Comment: please add your  views.py code.

Comment: @Ritankar Bhattacharjee when you are getting this error? during saving forms?

Comment: There is no view involved, the model will be filled from the admin panel directly, that is why I am using the code that I have posted. So i am facing the error when the field is being updated

Comment: Then you have to select user first. please select the user then trying to save from your admin panel.

Comment: I want to keep this field non editable so I have no way to get the user who is currently updating the model.

Comment: @Ritankar Bhattacharjee you are getting this error because when you trying to create or update object you are not selecting the user. please select the user then trying to create or update.

Comment: Please show me an example sir  by updating your ans

Comment: @Ritankar Bhattacharjee let  me clear first. Are you getting this error from your admin panel? where you are updating or creating object in your admin panel? or getting this error when submitting forms?

Comment: I am getting this error in the admin pannel. I am getting  this error while updating the field. There is no view handeling this, the user using the admin panel directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241874/discussion-between-boyenec-and-ritankar-bhattacharjee).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I overcame the error

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        current_user = get_current_authenticated_user()
        
        user =CustomUser.objects.get(email = current_user)

        self.uploaded_by = user.email

        super(Citation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here I am getting the user before directly saving it using **get_current_authenticated_user()** and then I am storing the user name (in my case email).

Answer (score 0):

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if change:
        obj.updated_by = str(request.user)
    else:
        obj.created_by = str(request.user)
    return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

`str()` type casting works.